# DRF and GraphQL Mesh Integration using OpenAPI method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, graphql, graphql-mesh

I am relatively new to graphql-mesh and trying to understand. I have connected my graphql version of DRF to mesh and it worked but when I am trying to connect it using OpenAPI I get errors like

[image: OpenAPI Integration Error]

**graphql-mesh configuration**

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "graphql-mesh",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "mesh dev"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@graphql-mesh/cli": "^0.88.5",
        "@graphql-mesh/graphql": "^0.96.3",
        "@graphql-mesh/openapi": "^0.97.5",
        "@graphql-mesh/runtime": "^0.97.4",
        "graphql": "^16.8.1"
    }
}
```

`.meshrc.yml`

```
sources:
  - name: DeveloperGround
    handler:
      openapi:
        source: http://localhost:8000/swagger.json
        baseurl: http://localhost:8000
```

**DRF configuration**

`project/settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'drf_yasg',
    'graphene_django',
]
```

`project/urls.py`

```
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView

schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="Snippets API",
      default_version='v1',
      description="Check description",
   ),
   public=True,
   permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)


urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('category/', include('mobiledeveloper.urls')),

   path('swagger<format>/', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0), name='schema-json'),
   path('swagger/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
   path('redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
   path('graphql/', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),

   path(
        "openapi<format>",
        drf_schema_view(
            title="Project", description="OpenAPI", version="1.0.0"
        ),
        name="openapi-schema",
    ),
]
```

If I use graphql configuration for the mesh then it is working but not when using OpenAPI. There is no any authentication or authorization used. All the API request are AllowAny kind. And I have used OpenAPI of Stripe and it worked fine, so I am guessing here that my backend requires more work but i cannot figure out what kind of work is required. So that my backend can also be implemented to mesh using OpenAPI.

**graphql-mesh configuration using graphql (working)**

`.meshrc.yml`

```
sources:
  - name: DeveloperGround
    handler:
      graphql:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8000/graphql/
```

> if anything else is required then comment. Thank you.